# spring security unable to login on centos environment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, spring-security

I am facing an unusual issue in my application. I am building an application in JavaEE using spring security for authentication and authorization, spring mvc and tomcat as an application server. I develop it on windows environment and when I upload it to the server (Amazon EC2 with centos 7), I am unable to login using spring security. Can anybody suggest me what environment issue it could be, I am also taking care of the case sensitive database table name also. Any ideas and suggestions??

Thanks,

**Update 01.10.2016** (Security configuration taken from OP's comments)

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/signupUser.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/tasks**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.html"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerData‌​Source">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crowdflow"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="userDetailService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.Jd‌​bcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: We need more information about your actual problem. Please show us your security configuration. Enable DEBUG logging for package `org.springframework.security` and post the generated logs here. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: <http auto-config="true">
   <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/signupUser.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/logout.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/tasks**" access="ROLE_USER" />
   <form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.html"/>
   <logout logout-success-url="/login.html" />
  </http>

Comment: <authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailService">
    <password-encoder hash="md5" />
   </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

Comment: <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crowdflow"/>
   <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
   <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
  </beans:bean>
  
  <beans:bean id="userDetailService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
   <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

Comment: I have pasted my security-config.xml file in parts. Please have a look at the configuration. However, with this configuration it is working fine in windows environment. Thanks

Comment: Do you have the mysql server running on your ec2 box in AWS? Do you have those ports open?

Comment: yes mysql server is running but let me check whether these ports are opened or not

Comment: So the port is opened because I am able to signup new users in my application. Signup users is my custom code and login users is handled by spring security. When I signup a new user is created in the users table but unable to login with the username and password

Comment: Please use the edit function on SO. Don't post additional information as comments. I added your security configuration to your question. Please provide logs too as I already mentioned in my first comment. Your configuration looks good so far.